# How can I allow iOS's native screen recording feature to capture Agora audio?

Tags: ios, agora.io, screen-recording

I would like to allow my users to capture recordings of my app's interface along with Agora audio using the system screen recording feature. I know that this is possible because the app Clubhouse also uses Agora and it allows for this.

I plan to show a banner to members of the channel when the app is being recorded and allow them to opt-out their channel if they so choose. But it is important to me that users are able to make and share these recordings on social media platforms as this will be one of the primary ways potential users learn about our app.

Is there some configuration option I need to enable that would allow this feature to work? Thanks!

Comment: I face this same issue, Did you find any solution with agora kit?

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on one agora based application

you need to just hold screen recording button for a second you will get one popover as the below screen shot for microphone on/off.
just turn on microphone and record video using system screen recording feature.[image]